# Warped Audio Sample

Tags: c++, algorithm, audio, music

I was asked this question and got no feedback, so I'd like to ask you for any feedback on my solution, Thanks!

Think of an audio sample as a rubber-band that you want to pin to a musical time ruler. The pins are called Warp Markers. A Warp Marker locks a specific point in the sample (in sample time) to a specific place in a measure (in beat time). You can use any number of Warp Markers to create an arbitrary mapping of the sample’s inherent rhythm to a musical meter. For the sake of this task, please assume the following behavior:

1. An audio clip contains a reference to a sample and a collection of Warp Markers.
2. There is at least one Warp Marker in the clip.
3. Between two Warp Markers, the tempo is constant.
4. The tempo before the first Warp Marker is the same as the tempo after the first Warp
   Marker.
5. The tempo after the last Warp Marker is specified separately in the input.
6. Beat time is measured in beats, sample time is measured in seconds, and tempo is
   measured in beats per second.
   Input description

There are 4 kinds of lines in the input:

1. Warp Marker definition
2. Definition of the tempo after the last marker
3. Sample time to beat time conversion
4. Beat time to sample time conversion

At least one Warp Marker and the tempo after the last Warp Marker should be defined before the first conversion; otherwise, these can appear in any order.
Each line consists of a keyword followed by numeric arguments. All numeric values are entered as doubles without units. Warp Marker and tempo definitions affect only the conversions that come later in the input.

```
marker <beat time> <sample time>
end_tempo <value>
s2b <sample time>
b2s <beat time>
```

Output description
For each of the s2b and b2s lines, the corresponding output time is printed without unit. Example

```
Input
marker 0.0 0.0
marker 1.0 5.0
end_tempo 10.0
b2s 0.5
s2b 6.0
Output
2.5 11.0
```

Here's my solution:

```
//one.h

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SAMPLER_H
#define SAMPLER_H

class Sampler {
    public:
        map<double, double> beats = {};
        map<double, double> samples = {};
        double endTempo;
        void addMarker(double beat, double sample);
        double b2s(double beat);
        double s2b(double sample);
};

#endif
```

and

```
// one.cc

#include "one.h"

using namespace std;

void Sampler::addMarker(double beat, double sample) {
    beats[beat] = sample;
    samples[sample] = beat;
}

double Sampler::b2s(double beat) {
    auto marker2 = beats.upper_bound(beat);

    if(marker2 == beats.begin()) marker2 = next(marker2);

    auto marker1 = prev(marker2);

    auto firstBeat = marker1->first;
    auto firstSample = marker1->second;

    double tempo;

    if(marker2 == beats.end()) {
        tempo = endTempo;
    } else {
        auto secondBeat = marker2->first;
        auto secondSample = marker2->second;

        tempo = (secondBeat - firstBeat) / (secondSample - firstSample);
    }

    return firstSample + ((beat - firstBeat) / tempo);
}

double Sampler::s2b(double sample) {
    auto marker2 = samples.upper_bound(sample);
    if(marker2 == samples.begin()) marker2 = next(marker2);
    auto marker1 = prev(marker2);

    auto firstBeat = marker1->second;
    auto firstSample = marker1->first;

    double tempo;

    if(marker2 == samples.end()) {
        tempo = endTempo;
    } else {
        auto secondBeat = marker2->second;
        auto secondSample = marker2->first;
        tempo = (secondBeat - firstBeat) / (secondSample - firstSample);
    }

    return firstBeat + ((sample - firstSample) * tempo);
}
```

and here's main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "one.h"

int main() {
  Sampler sampler;
  string str;
  while(true) {
    getline(cin, str);
    istringstream ss(str);
    string command;
    getline(ss, command, ' ');

    if(command == "marker") {
        string strBeat;
        string strSample;
        getline(ss, strBeat, ' ');
        getline(ss, strSample, ' ');
        double beat = stod(strBeat);
        double sample = stod(strSample);
        sampler.addMarker(beat, sample);
    } else if(command == "end_tempo") {
        string strTempo;
        getline(ss, strTempo, ' ');
        sampler.endTempo = stod(strTempo);
    } else if(command == "s2b") {
        string s;
        getline(ss, s, ' ');
        cout << sampler.s2b(stod(s)) << endl;
    } else if(command == "b2s") {
        string b;
        getline(ss, b, ' ');
        cout << sampler.b2s(stod(b)) << endl;
    } else {
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

and heres my tests

```
#include "one.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
namespace {

class OneMarker : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
     Sampler * sampler;
     virtual void SetUp() {      
         sampler = new Sampler();
         sampler->addMarker(3, 5);
         sampler->endTempo = 10;
     }

     virtual void TearDown() {
        delete sampler;
     }
};

TEST_F(OneMarker, Before) {
    EXPECT_EQ(4.6, sampler->b2s(-1));
    EXPECT_EQ(-57, sampler->s2b(-1));
}

TEST_F(OneMarker, After) {
    EXPECT_EQ(5.7, sampler->b2s(10));
    EXPECT_EQ(53, sampler->s2b(10));
}

class TwoMarkers : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
     Sampler * sampler;
     virtual void SetUp() {      
         sampler = new Sampler();
         sampler->addMarker(0, 0);
         sampler->addMarker(1, 5);
         sampler->endTempo = 10;
     }

     virtual void TearDown() {
        delete sampler;  
     }
};

TEST_F(TwoMarkers, Before) {
    EXPECT_EQ(-5.0, sampler->b2s(-1));
    EXPECT_EQ(-0.2, sampler->s2b(-1));
}

TEST_F(TwoMarkers, Between) {
    EXPECT_EQ(2.5, sampler->b2s(0.5));
    EXPECT_EQ(11.0, sampler->s2b(6.0));
}

TEST_F(TwoMarkers, After) {
    EXPECT_EQ(5.9, sampler->b2s(10));
    EXPECT_EQ(51, sampler->s2b(10));
}

TEST_F(TwoMarkers, Mutation) {
    EXPECT_EQ(5.9, sampler->b2s(10));
    EXPECT_EQ(51, sampler->s2b(10));
    sampler->addMarker(3,6);
    EXPECT_EQ(6.7, sampler->b2s(10));
    EXPECT_EQ(43, sampler->s2b(10));
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, I considered reviewing your earlier question but could not understand what it was supposed to do.  This explanation is much clearer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It's particularly bad to put that into a header file because it pollutes the global namespace.

### Use appropriate `#include`s

The header file contains these two lines:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

However, neither is actually required for the *interface*.  Also `main` does not need `<fstream>` but needs `<string>` but that is not included.

### Use better naming

The file named `one.h` is not well named.  The include guard name suggests that it is actually named `sampler.h` which is indeed a better name.

### Prefer `private` to `public` where practical

The `Sampler` class has data members `beats` and `samples` as public members.  Rather than do it that way, it would be better to keep it private because the class relies on an *invariant* -- namely that each entry in `beats` has a corresponding entry in `samples`.  Such invariants cannot easily be enforced if the data members are `public`.

### Use include guards correctly

The `one.h` file does have an include guard, which is good, but doesn't have it as the first thing in the file.  This can waste preprocessing time as contrasted with the usual (and recommended) method of putting the include guard as the very first non-comment line in the header.

### Use `const` where practical

The `b2s` and `s2b` functions don't alter the underlying object and so should be declared `const`.

### Reconsider the structures

It's unclear to me what, if anything, you intend to do with the beats and samples stored in the `Sampler` class, but the current method of having parallel `std::map` structures seems less than optimal.  If, as I infer, the context is music, both the sample and beat are increasing functions.  This suggests that they could easily be contained in a single `std::set<BeatTime>` where `BeatTime` is a simple private `struct` containing both `double`s.

With those changes, here's what the class declaration looks like:

```
class Sampler {
        struct BeatTime { 
            double beat, sample; 
            bool operator<(const BeatTime& rhs) const {
                return beat < rhs.beat;
            }
        };
        std::set<BeatTime> beats;
        std::set<BeatTime>::iterator sample_upper_bound(double sample) const;
    public:
        double endTempo;
        void addMarker(double beat, double sample);
        double b2s(double beat) const;
        double s2b(double sample) const;
};
```

Now the `addMarker` function is very simple:

```
void Sampler::addMarker(double beat, double sample) {
    beats.emplace(BeatTime{beat, sample});
}
```

And the `b2s` code is simplified:

```
double Sampler::b2s(double beat) const {
    auto marker2 = beats.upper_bound(BeatTime{beat, 0});
    double tempo{endTempo};
    if(marker2 == beats.begin()) {
        marker2 = next(marker2);
    }
    auto marker1 = prev(marker2);
    if(marker2 != beats.end()) {
        tempo = (marker2->beat - marker1->beat) / (marker2->sample - marker1->sample);
    }
    return marker1->sample + ((beat - marker1->beat) / tempo);
}
```

The `s2b` code is almost identical except that, of course, we can't use `upper_bound` directly.  Instead, it uses this:

```
std::set<Sampler::BeatTime>::iterator Sampler::sample_upper_bound(double sample) const {
    auto ret{beats.begin()};
    for ( ; ret != beats.end() && ret->sample <= sample; ++ret) 
    {}   
    return ret;
}
```

This makes the search linear rather than logarithmic, but it's unlikely to make a huge practical difference until the set becomes very large.